# Best method to get all posts under each sub categories

Tags: mongodb

I have nested categories in mongodb. The document of each category looks something like this:

```
{
    "id": "cat_id_3",
    "name": "category name",
    "parents": [cat_id_1, cat_id_2]
}
```

where `cat_id_1` is the top level category, `cat_id_2` is the next level an etc.

There is a collection for posts as well. Posts can be under any level of category. Right now I store only one category id in posts document, the one this particular post belongs to.

The problem with this is that I need to get all posts that are published under `cat_id_1` and under all of it's subcategories, in this example `cat_id_2` and `cat_id_3`. Or under `cat_id_2` and all of it's subcategories i.e. `cat_id_3`.

I'm considering several options and need some experienced advice.

1) I can get all the category ids that have `parents` array containing the id of the category, then get all posts where the id field is in the returned array of ids.

2) I can change the structure to contain all the parent category ids inside posts collection. That would avoid the need of additional query but it would be difficult to change the category structure later (e.g. add/delete categories).

So what would be the best approach in this case?

Comment: The way you're describing it you might have circular dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no generic answer to this. I think you have identified the sanest approaches.

Which of those works better for you depends on a number of factors:

- whether you expect a lot of re-ordering of categories
- what the number of posts in a category will be (i.e. how many documents would have to be repaired when categories are moved)
- how many reads you have

In a very read-heavy environment with little rearrangement of categories, denormalization definitely makes sense.

If there's a huge number of posts per category, they are changed very often and there are few reads, the two-query-strategy seems to make more sense.

Typically, your real-world application won't be very far on either side of the spectrum, so I'd go for what is easier to implement first (the two-query strategy) and fix it later if required.